# How can the smart contract auto execute the function in the Public chain eterscan testnet?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, nft, erc-721

i'm using auctions in Nft-marketplace smart contract and i want auto call the fnction of widraw wheneever auction ends , and transfer bidders bidds ti thier account ?

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum Alarm clock might be interesting for your use case, https://ethereum-alarm-clock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/